# Restricting access to Actions on Google to only members of G-Suite Account

Tags: google-oauth, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I'm creating an [Action on Google](https://developers.google.com/actions/) that if for our own corporate use (we are G-Suite customers).

How can I restrict access to the Action to only users who are signed into their corporate G-Suite account?

It looks like under the account linking area that I can add the Google Sign-in functionality, but I don't want to allow access to *anyone* with a Google account, only those associated with my G-Suite domain.

I think I could do this server-side on the POST webhook, just not return results if they aren't a corporate G-Suite user, but I'd rather stop the chain before that.

Answer (score 0):

There is no explicit setting to limit invocation to a certain group. If it's public, then anyone can invoke it. You could use sign-in to limit who has access to the core of your Action, but that's the only way you could do it.

Comment: That was my question, I am going to use sign-in to access the core action, how do I restrict it to just users from my G-Suite domain?

Comment: Check the email address.